# How to use EVGA GTX 970 to output to 2 Dell P2715Q monitors at 4K resolution at 60hz

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, displayport, 4k-resolution

My EVGA GTX970 has 1 DisplayPort, 1 HDMI 2.0 and 2x DVI ports.

Unfortunately, the HDMI port on Dell P2715Q is only HDMI 1.4. Therefore, I can output 4K resolution at 30Hz.

Is there a way to get 4k@60hz for both of these Dell P2715Q monitors?

Is there a DisplayPort hub which split the signal to dual monitors at 4K resolution at 60hz?

Answer (score 0):

When did you buy your monitors? According to [this support page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brdhs1/sln306595/setting-up-p2415q--p2715q-monitors-with-hdmi-20-support-4k-x-2k-60hz?lang=en) from Dell's website displays sold after February 2016 support HDMI 2.0 but it's not enabled from the factory.

You can enable HDMI 2.0 in your P2415Q or P2715Q flat panel displays purchased after February 2016 using the following steps:

1. Unplug all video cables from the display. (Leave only the power connected to the display.)
2. Power on the display.
3. Select the HDMI (MHL) input option. (A floating dialogue box will appear.)
4. Press and hold the button associated with the Green check mark for 6 to 8 seconds.
5. A dialogue box appear that states HDMI 1.4 Enable/Disable
   Select the option to Disable HDMI 1.4 support and press the button next to the green check mark to confirm the selection.
6. Re-connect the video cables to the display

Comment: Do you mind telling me if this solution works and a single GTX 970 is capable of running two P2715Q at 4K60? I'm planning to by a second display and I'm wondering if the graphic card will support them.

Comment: I bought this monitor before Feb 2016, so unfortunately it is only supporting HDMI 1.4. I switched to this monitor: QNIX 32" 4K -  it's supporting both HDMI 2.0 + DP 1.2